# Partials of $f(t+\theta)$ evaluated at $t=0$ versus partials of $f(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is infinitely differentiable with respect to its components. For $k\geq 1$ and $1\leq i_1,\ldots,i_k\leq n$, let's look at a $k$-th order mixed partial of a particular form:
$$
A\equiv\frac{\partial^k f(t+\theta)}{\partial t_{i_1}\ldots \partial t_{i_k}}\Bigg|_{t=0}.
$$
I'm trying to justify properly that the above expression equals
$$
B\equiv\frac{\partial^k f(\theta)}{\partial \theta_{i_1}\ldots \partial \theta_{i_k}}.
$$
But I'm being confused by the multivariate nature of the domain of $f$. Indeed, when $n=1$, the problem is simple
$$
A=f^{(k)}(t+\theta)\Big|_{t=0}=f^{(k)}(\theta)=B.
$$
Can you please help me? **Edit**: I think I got it. Can you please verify my answer below (posted as wiki)?

Answer (score 0):

Fix $k\geq 1$ and $1\leq i_1,\ldots,i_k\leq n$. Define the function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows
$$
g(z)=\frac{\partial^kf(z)}{\partial z_{i_1}\ldots\partial z_{i_k}}.
$$
Then it's immediate that $B=g(\theta)$. Let's look at $A$. By the Chain Rule,
$$
\frac{\partial f(t+\theta)}{\partial t_{i_k}}=\frac{\partial f(t+\theta)}{\partial(t_{i_k}+\theta_{i_k})}\frac{\partial(t_{i_k}+\theta_{i_k})}{\partial t_{i_k}}=\frac{\partial f(t+\theta)}{\partial(t_{i_k}+\theta_{i_k})}.
$$
Proceeding like this, we get
$$
\frac{\partial^k f(t+\theta)}{\partial t_{i_1}\ldots \partial t_{i_k}}=\frac{\partial^k f(t+\theta)}{\partial (t+\theta)_{i_1}\ldots \partial (t+\theta)_{i_k}}=g(t+\theta).
$$
Thus, the original claim that $A=B$ is equivalent to
$$
g(t+\theta)\Big|_{t=0}=g(\theta)
$$
which holds trivially.